# Angular 2+ Routing redirect

Tags: angular2-routing

This may seems as a silly question but I can't understand this routing

routes.ts:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'articles', component: ArticulosComponent },
  { path: 'article/:id', component: ArticuloComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'notfound' }
];
```

When access to `localhost:4200/article/6` the router redirects to `localhost:4200/#/home` but when manually wrote `localhost:4200/#/article/6` works fine.

First, note `#` symbol, why is it there and what different does it cause? And... I specify 'manually' because even through code adding the `#` symbol to the path (ex. `<a href="#/article/6"></a>`) keeps redirecting to `home`

The main question/problem is "Which would be the correct link or rule in other to load the correct component?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove # from route changing value of useHash in app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false }),
```

You can add `pathMatch: 'full'` with home and articles routes